# How to add a project to github with the github desktop application? The clone button is disabled after pasting the link of my repo

Tags: github, github-desktop

The clone button is disabled.

The Git folder is empty.
I got the link from github.com in my repo.

[image: Clone button is disabled]

This is how I copied the link from my repo:

[image: Copied link]

But when I paste the link to the application the clone button is still disabled.

Comment: Which is to say, try `chocolade1972/LineRenderer-Controller`

Comment: @mkrieger1 working once i changed to the url folder.

Answer (score 0):

The "GitHub.com" tab is meant to search for a repository by name, so you should enter something like `LineRenderer-Controller`, possibly including the username as well.

If you already have the full URL, you should put it in the "URL" tab.